# How is clustering used in the unsupervised training of a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, clustering

How is clustering used in the unsupervised training of a neural network? Can you provide an example?

Comment: This question seems like a student is asked to give a presentation about clustering to the entire class about clustering. In short the question is off topic and broad if not reformulated.

Comment: What is the topic for you?

Comment: @DuttaA I wouldn't say that homework questions are necessarily off-topic here. In this case, the user is asking for an example where clustering is involved in the unsupervised training of an NN. I've reformulated the question to make it more acceptable.

Comment: @nbro still quite broad.

Comment: @DuttaA If he's asking only for one example, then this should be ok. If he's asking to describe all cases, yes, this is too broad.

Comment: @nbro Can you help me bro? =(

Comment: @RamedlawVocinnas Maybe later I will try to give an answer, but I wouldn't surely count on this.

Comment: @nbro Why?! =((